# Connecting an Android application with database without using PHP

Tags: php, android

Can we connect an Android application with database without using PHP?
Though I have done it using PHP but it gets hectic So Is there any other way?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite perhaps?

Comment: Hello, Pam. I would recommend you to take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It would be easier to be answer if you make you question more clear and undestandable. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some alternatives to connect to a database without using hosted server (PHP)

## Firebase

You can use Firebase Database (Realtime Database or Cloud Firestone).

It is a easy serverless option to integrate your android app.

There is **Realtime Database**:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database

There is **Cloud Firestone**:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore?hl=pt-br

Basically Cloud Firestone is a improved Realtime Database, but you can read more here to decide with one is better for your case:
https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/realtime-database-vs-cloud-firestore-which-database-is-suitable-for-your-mobile-app-87e11b56f50f

There are difference between pricing between the both of them, but it has a Free Tier access using Spark Plan.

You can also handle image/files storage inside the firebase, with is pretty useful.

More info about price: https://firebase.google.com/pricing?hl=pt-br

I might be expensive than create an API that connect to a hosted Database, but I work for the easy to setup.

## SQL Lite

If you only need local storage you can use sqlite: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite

Notice that this is will only be available on the user device. If you need some info across devices I recommend using Firebase or some other server service made for storage.